# More efficent way of finding the index of an elements' class in `List`

Tags: c#, selenium

So I have this code where I gather the elements then write all the class names to a List then find out the index of that specific class.

This to me seems very longwinded, maybe I should use linq however my brain cannot fathom another way to do it (it is friday!!).

```
    private void Pagination()
    {
        List<string> classnames = new List<string> { };
        var pagination = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ul[data-type='order-sitebundle']> li"));
        //var activepage = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[data-type='order-sitebundle']> li[class='active']"));
        foreach (var item in pagination)
        {
            classnames.Add(item.GetAttribute("className"));
        }

        int actibve = classnames.IndexOf("active");
        pagination[actibve++].Click();
```

Comment: Why not write a selector to find that element directly? or find the next one after the active one

Comment: @lauda I need to find out the class so i can select the next element in the list, which is why `pagination[actibve++]`

Answer (score 0):

Find the element that is active:

```
ul[data-type='order-sitebundle'] li[class='active']
```

You don't have to use `actibve++`, find the next `li` after the active one:

```
ul[data-type='order-sitebundle'] li[class='active'] + li
```